# Heat sink designing for an automotive grade motor controller

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, motor-controller, heat, heatsink

I am working on an electric vehicle development project.  I am using a motor controller to drive a 3 phase induction motor. The motor controllers' input supply is 48 volts, and they sink a maximum of 250 amperes (for a short time.)

The problem I am experiencing is that when the vehicle is at a hill, the motor controller is overheated, and due to that, the motor is turned off and, until it is cooled down, it cannot be restarted. Due to this problem, I am looking for a suitable heat sink. I need your support to verify that I have followed the correct procedure to determine the required heat sink.

- If the efficiency of the motor controller is 90% (assumed.)
- The power generated as heat is: 5 kW x 0.10 = 500 W (heating power.)
- Case maximum temperature: 75 °C
- Ambient temperature: 30 °C.
- Volumetric thermal resistance: 150 (refer to the provided link)
- Fins are also available in heat sinks.

(I used this online calculator to find the desired heat sink size : https://celsiainc.com/resources/calculators/heat-sink-size-calculator/)

Are my calculations correct, and is something wrong here? When I calculate, it suggests that I use a large heat sink for my application. Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Input is 48VDC and output is 48VAC

Comment: There's no way we have enough information from the above. Heat is removed three ways --- as I'm sure you know. And radiation may be significant, itself depending upon shape factors, material emissivities, etc. You must have collected data on the rising thermal temperatures. The shape of that curve over time before shutdown will tell *some* useful things. True, some (and I mean *some* as in *uncommon*) theorists can do a lot from detailed measurements of your mechanicals and electronics and transducers (motor.) But that's not going to happen here, nor with what little you've given.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually, our motor overheats when it sinks and sources maximum current for more than 5 seconds. Actually, this is a very rare case, and we are testing this as well. This condition can occur when vehicles are on the hill with full payload and try to move forward.

Actually, my question is, when deciding the heat source power, have I correctly decided the power (500 W)? For 500W heat dissipation, it requires a large heat sink. and please consider that volumetric thermal resistance is 200 (gentle air).

Comment: The only way to find out if it is enough is by building it or simulating it. Making a heatsink bigger brings diminishing returns because heat transfer inside the heatsink is neither infinite nor instantaneous... But getting rid of 500W with a dT of only 45°C is tough without active cooling.

Comment: Thank you vert much. That is good answer.

Comment: Nitpicking: 5 kW * 0.1 is confusing compared to 5 kW * (1-0.9) but the result is of course the same. I took the liberty of editing your kelvinwatt to kilowatt. You also need a unit for _”Volumetric thermal resistance: 150”_

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciate.